# Всплывающая подсказка Bootstrap popover с задержкой при наведении

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, popover

Данный скрипт открывает всплывающую подсказку (Bootstrap popover) при наведении мыши с задержкой в 2 секунды, но есть одна проблема, если я навожу курсор на 2 секунды, появится всплывающая подсказка, и если навести курсор мыши на само всплывающее окно, а затем перевести его за пределы всплывающего окна, то всплывающее окно не закрывается.

```js
var timerReady = false
var showPopup;
$(".popver-info").popover({
    trigger: "manual",
    html: true,
    animation: false,
    placement: "bottom"
  })

  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    var _this = this;

    timerReady = true

    showPopup = setTimeout(function() {
      if (timerReady) {
        $(_this).popover("show");
      }
    }, 2000)
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(showPopup)
    timerReady = false
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $(_this).popover("hide");
      }
    }, 300);
  });
```

```css
.popver-info {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  background: #353a40;
  color: #d8ff02;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 1</div>
<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 2</div>
<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 3</div>
<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я убрал вам эту проверку `if (!$(".popover:hover").length). Не знаю зачем она там была

```js
var timerReady = false
var showPopup;
$(".popver-info").popover({
    trigger: "manual",
    html: true,
    animation: false,
    placement: "bottom"
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    var _this = this;

    timerReady = true

    showPopup = setTimeout(function() {
      if (timerReady) {
        $(_this).popover("show");
      }
    }, 2000)
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    clearTimeout(showPopup)
    timerReady = false
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(_this).popover("hide");
    }, 300);
  });
```

```css
.popver-info {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  background: #353a40;
  color: #d8ff02;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 1</div>
<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 2</div>
<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 3</div>
<div class="popver-info" role="button" data-content="текст всплывающей подсказки">ссылка 4</div>
```